# Why does form-post get executed automatically when clicking button?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have a button inside a form in asp.net core.  The form has it's own submit button which is supposed to trigger the create action when it is clicked. I have another button insde the form which is just calling a piece of javascript code. I don't understand why when I click on the button to call the javascript, the post action "Create" is called also afterwards. That is I see the alert box and then I get redirected by the action. I just want to display the alert without this triggering the action method.

```js
function ValidateName() {
  var name = document.getElementById('btnName').value;
  alert(name);

}
```

```html
<form asp-action="Create">
  <div class="form-group">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
      <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
      <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
        <button id="btnName" class="btn btn-primary btn-md center-block" Style="width: 150px;" OnClick="ValidateName()">Validate</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Créer" class="btn btn-default" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It does not display the alert and still gets redirected.

Comment: Change it to `button type="button"`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to prevent the default behavior

```
function ValidateName(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name= document.getElementById('btnName').value;
    alert(name);

}
```

Comment: It's not showing the alert now but still gets redirected. So still not good.